# Get current date and time from Google in Android

Tags: android, date, time, server, ntp

I have some experience in Android application development. Now we developed an Android application where we need the exact date and time from Google or the internet. Already I test some code from Stack Overflow and from some other sites, but it did not work correctly. The app crashed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you mean to get the GMT time?

Comment: This doesn't work like that.  you should show what you've tried and what is the problem, and we'll try to help fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private long getTime() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://time.is/Unix_time_now";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
    String[] tags = new String[] {
            "div[id=time_section]",
            "div[id=clock0_bg]"
    };
    Elements elements= doc.select(tags[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <tags.length; i++) {
        elements = elements.select(tags[i]);
    }
    return Long.parseLong(elements.text() + "000");
}
```

Gradle:

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

Comment: The app is not crashed . But gives null value

Comment: Have you added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission?

Comment: Timeapi seems to be offline

Comment: Did my answer help you? Please click on the green checkmark to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is enough to get what you wanted:

Using the HttpGet, Client and Response, I manage to get a server's current time from the response Date Header. I can call this all the times I want and will get confident responses (Google is almost 100% available and I can trust on getting correct Date and Time)

```
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            String dateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
            //Here I do something with the Date String
            System.out.println(dateStr);

        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: HttpClient is not support anymore in SDK 23 and UP

Answer (score 0):

ou can get time from internet time servers using the below program

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.time.TimeTCPClient;

public final class GetTime {

public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
        try {
            // Set timeout of 60 seconds
            client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
            // Connecting to time server
            // Other time servers can be found at : http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi#
            // Make sure that your program NEVER queries a server more frequently than once every 4 seconds
            client.connect("nist.time.nosc.us");
            System.out.println(client.getDate());
        } finally {
            client.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

1.You would need [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library for this to work. Download the library and add to your project build path.

(Or you can also use the trimmed Apache Commons Net Library here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjxjv7phkb8xfhh/commons-net-3.1.jar. This is enough to get time from internet )

2.Run the program. You will get the time printed on your console.